# pip install python module , but python shell not see it

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
> PS C:\Python34\Scripts> pip3.4 install --upgrade pyspeak
Requirement already up-to-date: pyspeak in c:\python34\lib\site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: pytest==2.3.4 in c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from pyspeak)
Requirement already up-to-date: simplejson==3.1.3 in c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from pyspeak)
Requirement already up-to-date: requests==1.2.0 in c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from pyspeak)
Requirement already up-to-date: py>=1.4.12 in c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from pytest==2.3.4->pyspeak)
Cleaning up...
>
```

the pip list show me

```
> PS C:\Python34\Scripts> pip3.4 list 

 PySpeak (0.1.5)
```

when I try to working with this (new cmd shell, also PowerShell) , I got this :

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyspeak
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pyspeak'
>>>
```

Comment: Please include full terminal output that also includes python version

Comment: I just tried to install, same issue. And older versions wont install. I think this library is just broken. Try `pip install thingspeak` instead